# couldn't install selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Windows 10, 32bit, and Python 3.9
I tried to install selenium library with pip and downloaded `.whl` file and followed all solutions I found on the internet but it returns this:

```
>>> pip install selenium  
  File "<stdin>", line 1  
    pip install selenium   
        ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> python pip install selenium  
  File "<stdin>", line 1    
    python pip install selenium    
           ^     
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> py -m pip install selenium   
  File "<stdin>", line 1   
    py -m pip install selenium    
          ^     
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also tried in cmd but...

```
C:\Users\user>pip install selenium    
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file .
```

I also tried the same but added the location of python.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I assume, you're trying to do this in the Python interpreter. What you need to do is to do this command in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've pasted, it looks as if you've tried to use `pip install selenium` in a python file/terminal. It is a command to be run in the windows cmd, like so:
[image: picture of cmd]

Note - your installation might look different if you already have urrlib3 installed, that's perfectly fine.

EDIT:

Seems you've edited your question accordingly and `pip install selenium` doesn't work either, so try:
`python -m pip install selenium`

Comment: thanks but i also tried cmd and it said basically pip not recognised

Comment: Have you tried the other option as well? python -m pip install selenium

Answer (score 0):

This code is working in my pc

```
!pip install selenium
```